# Can't fit three span4 elements into span12 container

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm still learning Twitter Bootstrap, but I have a weird problem. I used 960gs before and never had such issues. So, I want to fit three `.span3` elements into `.span12` container. My code is as follows:

```
                <ul class="dropdown-menu span12 row">
                    <li class="span4">asd</li>
                    <li class="span4">asd</li>
                    <li class="span4">asd</li>
                </ul>
```

I don't understand, why last `.span4` element falls down. I thought that first element would have its `margin-left` nullified or something. What did I do wrong?

Entire code: http://jsfiddle.net/KPzBH/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And I solved it. A bit much code, but works good using only Bootstrap's classes with no additional definitions of width.

Here it is:

```
<li class="dropdown"><a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">gry <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu span12">
                            <li>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="span3 offset1">
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>asd</li>
                                            <li>sss</li>
                                            <li>bb</li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="span3">
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>asd</li>
                                            <li>sss</li>
                                            <li>bb</li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="span3">
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>asd</li>
                                            <li>sss</li>
                                            <li>bb</li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
```

Answer (score 1):

add a div of class "row-fluid" instead of "row"...

Comment: Please describe solution in more details. The answer is too short for the question that was asked 3 months ago.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.com. Can you think of ways to improve your answer, such as including a more elaborate code snippet or demonstration?

Answer (score 0):

It should be is wrong

```
<li class="dropdown"><a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">gry <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu row-fluid">
            <li class="span4">asd</li>
            <li class="span4">asd</li>
            <li class="span4">asd</li>
        </ul>
</li>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rtQa6/)

Since you are using a `span12` as the parent, I would recommend you to remove that `row` and replace it with the `dropdown-menu` row

Comment: I placed a jsFiddle in my question. For now, your answer doesn't work.

Comment: @TomekBuszewski I would suggest you to add a custom class to the `ul` like `wide-dropdown` and add a css rule with the desired width like `.wide-dropdown {width: 550px}`

Comment: One of the reasons I use CSS frameworks is widths that can adjust to various deviced via classes like `grid-12` or `span12`. Setting fixed widths (and even setting various media queries later) while using CSS frameworks isn't a good solution for me.

Comment: I don't see a way to make it work the way you are expecting without applying some kind of hacks. If you find any answer please let me know

Comment: I posted my answer with an answer in it.